# DBI Connect issue using perl

Tags: perl, odbc, ssms

I have a connection through Microsoft SQL Server management studio that allows me to connect to a cluster database with a display name of the server and username along with password...

I have tried to connect my perl script to this database but keep getting this error in my IDE

```
DBI connect('ntcasdg3-db2\ntcafde4-db1','helping',...) failed: 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) 
at C:/Users/harry/workspace/DataEx/DexDatabaseConnect.pl line 9 couldn't open database:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002);
 stopped at C:/Users/harry/workspace/DataEx/DexDatabaseConnect.pl line 9.
```

**Does the management studio use a different method to connect to the database that isn't available within Perl?**

This is my current code:

```
#!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w

use DBI;

$db_user = "helping";
$db_pass = "helper";
$dsn_name= 'dbi:ODBC:ntcasdg3-db2\ntcafde4-db1';

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn_name, $db_user, $db_pass) or die "couldn't open database: $DBI::errstr; stopped";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<End_SQL) or die "Couldn't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";
SELECT vendor FROM dbo.dex_vendor_info
End_SQL

$sth->execute() or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr; stopped";
```

Comment: Perhaps this SO question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202962/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mssql-database-using-perls-dbi-module-in-windows

Comment: @That did it thanks...I had to just set up my odbc driver in the syswow64 folder's config and it finally connected...Thanks for the detour..