# IIS Connection IIS Basic User Settings Specific User Cannot Connect to SQL Server using Perl DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, iis, dbi

My Perl IIS web application is getting an SSL Error when the Perl DBI tries to connect to my MS SQL Server database version 11.0.7001 (that's what is listed in SQL Server Manager). The Perl application runs under IIS, and my IIS Basic User Settings Connection is set to Specific User (Domain Administrator).

The SQL Sever database resides on the same system as IIS. The distribution of Perl is Strawberry Perl; IIS' version is 8.5.9600.16384.

I can connect to the database using the SQL Server Manager locally on the server as well as remotely from my workstation. The connection type is SQL username and password. The IIS application listens on port 8085. The IIS permissions are not restricted, and there is no SQL server connection string as part of IIS.

The first page of the application loads, but this first page does not try to connect to the SQL Server database.

I have been looking at Stackoverflow posts -- like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202962/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mssql-database-using-perls-dbi-module-in-windows#203095) -- for a while, and have tried some of the suggestions like making a system DSN (which tests correctly), instead of a DSN string in Perl.

None of the suggestions have helped, and many but not all of the posts are dealing with security and certificates, not an application that is behind a firewall. In other words, I do not have security turned on.

To the best of my knowledge there is no security turned on for this application, and Named Pipes and TCP/IP ***were already turned on***, as was suggested in one of the posts I read.

Here is the error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (SQL-01000) at ../../include/DbArgs.pm line 266.
DBI connect('driver={SQL Server};server=arlsql\arlsql;database=BuildingPermit;uid=user;pwd=pwd','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SSL Security error (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
```

Any suggestions on what to try next would be appreciated.

***Edit 1/6/2020***

I need to add that my C# client application using .Net ODBC objects successfully accesses the same database on which the web-based Perl DBI code fails. The username and password are the same for the client application as that used in the Perl CGI.

The IIS user for this application runs as the domain administrator, but when creating the DBI connection uses the same username and password. The database is set up for SQL username and password, and, as stated previously, there is no security set, at least that I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question but is instead a workaround. I consider the following a workaround, because I would still like to know why the DBI call failed with a specific user.

I switched my IIS Basic User Settings Connection from *Specific User* (Domain Administrator) to *Application User (pass-through authentication)*.

After making this change and restarting IIS, the Perl DBI connection worked, but why?

Comment: That's more a question about the IIS/MS SQL security model (which I know nothing about) rather than perl DBI.